# How can I trigger update without user interaction and update view hockey sdk ios?

Tags: ios, enterprise, hockeyapp

I have a requirement to trigger update automatically for enterprise app without user interaction can you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of HockeySDK for iOS. However, since the SDK is open source, you can modify the code to your liking and use a custom build of the SDK in your app: http://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/

It is possible to show a simplified version of the UI in form of a simple dialog using [showDirectInstallOption](https://www.hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/5.1.2/Classes/BITUpdateManager.html#/c:objc(cs)BITUpdateManager(py)showDirectInstallOption).

Note though, that there will always be at least some user interaction because iOS itself requires user consent before installing a new side-loaded app or an update of such an app.